# Symfony2 Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini Errror

Tags: php, symfony, timezone, settings

Just started my first symfony2 project, and after installation on running `http://127.0.0.1/inventory/web/config.php` i got below message.

```
This script will guide you through the basic configuration of your project. You can also do the same by editing the ‘app/config/parameters.yml’ file directly.
**MAJOR PROBLEMS**
Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:
Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).
* Changes to the php.ini file must be done in "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini".
```

I have set `date.timezone = "Asia/Karachi"` in following files

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

and this too in `AppKernel.php`

```
public function init()
{
    // get rid of Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Karachi' );
    parent::init();
}
```

but still the same error.
however, when i run this `php -i | grep "timezone"`command on console i got this,

```
Default timezone => Asia/Karachi
date.timezone => Asia/Karachi => Asia/Karachi
```

More on running phpinfo() function on test.php file i got this,

[image]

Comment: in `phpinfo()` confirm the loaded configuration file.

Comment: and did you restart the server after changing in `apache2/php.ini` ?

Comment: also check your .htaccess and sources maybe it have something like ini_set directive

Comment: @Jigar, No, but now by running `sudo service apache2 restart` the error disappears , but got below error `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: its a warning, you can ignore. or set `ServerName` in apache2 config. search for it on google, you should get it, very basic.